# Did the Andorians evolve on their homeworld?

Tags: star-trek, andorian

Andoria is [an ice moon with mid-summer temps of -28°](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Andoria) (assuming [Celsius?](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Celsius)).  They seem to survive only via technological adaptation.  Did they originate on another planet/moon?  How could they evolve on this ice world?  Was it previously more temperate? Is there an in-universe explanation?

Comment: I find your tagging of this question offensive, and the SE software deems the change "too trivial" to let me correct it myself.  RESPECT OUR NERD TURF WARS, SE!!1!

Comment: @jwodder holy smokes! oops, my bad

Comment: Which corrections are needed? I make trivial corrections all the time, and I'm going for a gold badge.

Comment: i had tagged it STAR-WARS!  womp womp

Comment: I am going to assume you did that by forgetting Star Wars even exists.  ;)

Comment: damnyouautocorrect...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, no - the Andorians aren't from the planet.  They originated on an ice moon of Andoria.

The best evidence I can think of that they originated from that system would be the [Aenar](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Aenar).  They're a sub-species that diverged from Andorians long, long ago, and are naturally blind.  Andorians long believed them to be a myth, until they made contact in 2104.

Otherwise, the [Andorian first contact with the Vulcans](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Andorian_history#Early_history_and_contact_with_Vulcan) would be my best guess:  The Vulcans had their own version of the Prime Directive for centuries, and did not contact the Andorians until the 1900s.  This strongly implies that the Andorians didn't have spacefaring technology until about that point, so they'd have to originate on Andoria.

Comment: He had the correct place, he just incorrectly referred to it as a planet.

Comment: The moon was also a cold place..